# How to disable Client-side Validation for an XPage?

Tags: validation, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I know i can disable for the server or application in the xsp.properties via:

```
xsp.client.validation=false
```

And at the control level via:

```
disableClientSideValidation="true"
```

Short of setting disableClientSideValidation for each control, is there any way to disable at the XPage level?

Comment: Good question.  My guess is no, since that attribute is tied to the control, not the page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.properties>
        <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.validation" value="false" />
    </xp:this.properties>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: When I add the parameter to an XPage that contains a custom control with a number of input fields one of which is a RTF I get the error when I submit the document & it does validation:
---------------------------
xpWFSDemo
---------------------------
An error occurred while updating some of the page.
   dijit.byId("view:_id1:_id2:_id3:dynamicContent1:_id5:_id6:callback1:_id147:callback1:_id150:projectSummary") is undefined
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

projectSummary is the RTF, If I remove the RTF field or if I remove the property it works without error.