# Disable ClientSide Validation

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

in this posting:
[How to disable Client-side Validation for an XPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212756/how-to-disable-client-side-validation-for-an-xpage)

Sven demonstrated setting the property to disable the client side validation.

```
<xp:this.properties>
        <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.validation" value="false" />
    </xp:this.properties>
```

I tried this in a test XPage and it works great, I then tried it in my application and I get an error when the Submit button is clicked that my Rich Text Field is undefined. I have a custom control that contains all the input and validation and it is called from the an ext Lib Application Layout Control. I have removed most everything I can from my App Layout but when I do a submit it does the correct validation but also gives the message:

```
---------------------------
xpWFSDemoInput
---------------------------
An error occurred while updating some of the page.
   dijit.byId("view:_id1:_id2:_id3:_id4:callback1:_id145:callback1:_id148:inputRichText1") is undefined
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I place my input custom control inside a new Xpage, set the parameter on the Xpage and run it and it works fine, it sees the RichText and processes it correctly. So there would appear to be something in the App Layout that is causing problems.
I will try putting the Ext Lib Applayout into an XPage and see what happens.

Some further info -- I found the problem code which is some client side script that does a periodic time check. No idea why it hates the RTF though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable client-side validation for the application, you can do so in the Xsp Properties in the application. You can also do it in an xsp.properties file on the server. Check out XPages Portable Command Guide for more details on this and all xsp.properties settings